# Resolve Template Parameter Pack Overload Ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++20, template-specialization, c++-concepts, parameter-pack

## Minimum Example

I have the following struct with *a few* specializations:

```cpp
template<size_t ...Tpar>
struct Base{};

struct X{};
struct Y{};

template<typename T, size_t ...Tpar>
struct Spline: Base<Tpar...>{}; // general type

template<typename T>
struct Spline<T>: Base<>{}; // specialization 1

template<typename T, size_t n>
struct Spline<T,n>: Base<n>{}; // specialization 2

template<size_t ...Tpar>
struct Spline<X,Tpar...>: Base<Tpar...>{}; // specialization 3

template<size_t ...Tpar>
struct Spline<Y,Tpar...>: Base<Tpar...>{}; // specialization 4
```

The implementation bodies are lengthy each, and have been spared for a minimum example.

## Error

The following ambiguity arises for `X` (and analogously for `Y`):

```cpp
int main(){
  Spline<X,56> sx56; // error: compiler cannot decide between spec. 2 and spec. 3.
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gBspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcWaJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgmG25OCgTEmKz72CYaAIJX1wSYLEkGD/tuaQBemAD6BADUADogQAVJINC53Y7ELwOP4WJhKEwAdisSIAIvsrDdIScYf8ABrI1EYjZY65QvF/ACaRORJLJdweTxemDeBAAnklGKxMH9gaQ/p8fv8gQDQeCNpcbhTYUJnlMQHCEayDuLiKKISi6Zi/gB6XV/YCMWJiP4crl3RmPZ5MV4Hc3cth8iHS3Gy%2BVhN7Ai6K%2BGIg6a4k6/WCrnIPBiPAfW0ZP5cS03Jk2u1uB3MJ38wVR4V/Bgu8lu/5y2hTL2kPOS33Kt4Vy5a9HBg0KMMRkvRxwCP5mBP3a0st5C36AkFg4j5mVFj0qtz40hqjWVpX%2BtzzoGB7WkvVNluR9uxjY9pP9g6DkUjiVSgvQ90lz0HKlz0cL7BV5ergHrhubkPN6qtqMxp2kg9qE/wsEwoQQHMtI3H8fzFqWByzgArPEFyCqoqGNn8sTECQipoE8dCxH8ogMAwqD/Fg4ZYH8MQEAA7pgjChtUAJdn8hjoKxyDsRsH7YuiHALLQnDIbwfgcFopCoJwbjWNYgpLCsvKbDwpAEJowkLAA1iAGz8QZRnGSZiSiRwkgSVpMmcLwCggBoGlaQscCwEghFJMRZAUBAHleSAwBcBsARYAAbngqwAGp4JgDEAPJcpJ6k0LQDzEPZEBRNZUShA07KcOpOXMMQ7JxVE2jVJp3C8IRbCCHFDC0PlUm8FgUReMAbhiLQ9nVaQWDgUY4gtf1eCnDUoWYL10mYKo1ReA8BW8KBmDmdJJZRMQeUeFg1knHgLBLQsVAGMACjRbFCWMEtMiCCIYjsFIt3yEoajWboXD6IYxgKZY%2Bh4FE9mQAsqBJB2DC9bwqCTcQxB4FgQNQbYq2VRkLgMO4ngtCAACcjnBFMJRlCA0gpGk4OjH4eN5OTGS9ETAzSO04NdCMWM5NTzO1BM9P9HETMTJTuOOcc3S8zM/MLAoymrBIIliVZI2yRwfyqAAHPEAC08SSIayDIHG/FmH8EC4IQJB/Gpcy8FVWhzLp%2BmGSZzsGWZnCWeW1nK3ZDlOS1LkwIgIBLAQSQLeQlB%2BfQxDhDynDq1rOt6wbQUAmYvCYPgRBw%2Bgej8HdojiE9%2BcvSo6gjR9pAMVtSRHfoCue0rnBxQtYf/KgVCqxr2u68A%2BuG2nJseER0eW2YGxcNbft2w7BkAi7Lv1xZivSd7ti%2B7b2lL%2Bnjer7Z09bzDaTOJIQA%3D%3D%3D)

## Why the Overloading

I have one customer class code that is supposed to yield a wide range of different bahaviours depending on i) mainly the type and ii) subsequently the existence and value of additional template arguments. I have tried different things and this appeared convenient for what I am trying to do -- until now, where I wish to re-introduce `Tpar...` into specializations 3 and 4.

## What I expected

I expected that specialization 3 would be used, because `X` is a type restriction whereas `n` is only an amount specialization.

## What I want

I would like to declare that specialization 3 is to be used in this case. Since the implementations of 3 and 4 are huge, I would like to perform this declaration somewhere concisely.

## Workaround

If a timely fix was mandatory, I would use the following:

```cpp
template<typename T,size_t ...Tpar>
using Spline = std::conditional_t< std::is_value_t<T,X> , Spline_Spec3<Tpar...> , /*...*/ >;
```

But that would be

1. error-prone
2. difficult to read
3. require nested std::conditional_t for X and Y
4. require renaming of specialization class names

Comment: Do you know about `requires`? You add a condition on specialization (2) to stop it from being used for `X` and `Y`.

Comment: Ah, that's what it`s for? (because I tried it today for something that I was then instead able to achieve with static_assert.) The examples are so difficult to understand. I will dig into that.

Comment: It just lets you add a condition to a template (or specialization), that prevents it from being used for certain template arguments. A `static_assert` would give you a compilation error, but `requires` would cause fallback to different specializations, which is what you want.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. Nice, indeed what I want. I am currently reading into it :) I will post my attempt here once I figure it out :)

Comment: @MarekR. Thanks, fixed it :)

Comment: @kaisong please [edit] question and keep it up to date. so it is clear for evryone. Also specify your C++ standard (C++20 concepts makes fix simple).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat. Can you help me? I have a hard time defining a concept that is non-tautological. ``template<typename T>
concept is_default_floating_point_type = requires(T t){ std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T,X> or std::is_same_v<T,Y>, std::false_type{}, std::true_type{}>(); };`` Before that, I tried ``{ not (std::is_same_v<T,X> or std::is_same_v<T,Y>); };``

Comment: @MarekR. I added concepts to hashtags. I removed ``X`` from ``Base`` inheritance. Did I miss something?

Comment: Test this: constraint 1 and 2 with `requires not std::is_same_v<T, X>` and 5 with `requires (sizeof...(Tpar) > 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by @HolyBlackCat.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

template<size_t ...Tpar>
struct Base{};

struct X{};
struct Y{};

template<typename T>
concept is_default_floating_point_type = requires(T t){ 
    requires not( std::is_same_v<T,X> or std::is_same_v<T,Y> );
};

template<typename T, size_t ...Tpar>
struct Spline: Base<Tpar...>{}; // general type

template<typename T>
struct Spline<T>: Base<>{}; // specialization 1

template<typename T, size_t n>
    requires is_default_floating_point_type<T>
struct Spline<T,n>: Base<n>{}; // specialization 2

template<size_t ...Tpar>
struct Spline<X,Tpar...>: Base<Tpar...>{
  Spline(){ std::cout << "hi.\n"; }
}; // specialization 3

template<size_t ...Tpar>
struct Spline<Y,Tpar...>: Base<Tpar...>{}; // specialization 4

int main(){
  Spline<X,56> sx56; // now compiler selects specialization 3
}
```

Comment: The concept can be simplified to `template<typename T>
concept is_default_floating_point_type = !(std::is_same_v<T,X> || std::is_same_v<T,Y>);`. Also the concept can be removed altogether, if you don't mind a more clunky notation: you can write the condition directly in the template: `template <typename T, size_t n> requires(!(std::is_same_v<T,X> || std::is_same_v<T,Y>))`.